# Expected time efficiency

Tags: file, runtime, binary-search

I have 2 database files and among those one I had to search for which I used 4 methods namely: in-memory sequential, in-memory binary, disk sequential and disk binary. The file which needed to be searched was 20Kb in size. The expected running time for these 4 programs should have been

`disk sequential > disk binary > in-memory sequential > in-memory binary` but its coming out to be 
`disk binary > disk sequential > in-memory sequential > in-memory binary`.

Disk binary is taking around 1.5 sec more than the disk sequential. Why so?
I have calculated the time as printing the time before opening the file and then after opening the file and doing the search.

Thanks!

Comment: Can we see your search and timing implementations?  Perhaps just any parts you're not sure about in terms of performance.  Also, for the in memory ones, are you counting the time of loading the file into memory?  Assuming no, but never hurts to ask.

Comment: @Corbin I am counting the time of loading the file into memory.

Comment: As Simone said, when for some run times, the behavior of the run time is different with very small sets of data.  From thinking about Simone's answer and from thinking about your code, I think what's probably happening now is that the memory searching is reading the entire file, whereas the seeking is only touching parts of it.  Seeking over chunks is going to be faster than reading them, so the memory one is taking longer because it's reading more.  Maybe anyway :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can depends on the small size of your file; disk is not like main memory, it's divided in blocks and your file won't be probably bigger than 20 blocks. 
So log_2(20) is about 5 and then binary search won't be better unless what you're searching for is after the fifth block.